# Uso un Thread Runnable o un Intent Service?

Tags: java, android, hilos

cuando usamos por ejemplo

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                try {
                    DatagramSocket clientsocket= new DatagramSocket(5005);
                    byte[] receivedata = new byte[30];
                    while(true) {
                        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(receivedata, receivedata.length);
                        Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");
                        clientsocket.receive(recv_packet);
                        String receivedstring = new String(recv_packet.getData());
                        Log.d("UDP", " Received String: " + receivedstring);
                        InetAddress ipaddress = recv_packet.getAddress();
                        int port = recv_packet.getPort();
                        Log.d("UDP", "IPAddress : " + ipaddress.toString());
                        Log.d("UDP", "Port : " + Integer.toString(port));
                    }
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    Log.e("UDP", "Socket Error", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("UDP", "IO Error", e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Estamos generando un hilo independiente a la activity que seguirá ejecutando el `run()` hasta que cerremos la APP o lo detengamos nosotros de alguna forma? Y si es así. ¿Podemos interactuar con la interfaz desde este hilo? Actualmente uso un Intent Service pero quizá esta opción sea más adecuada.

Comment: Para interactuar con la interfaz puedes crear un interface para pasar datos entre el hilo secundario y el principal.

Answer (score 1):

puntualmente que necesitas hacer? los intent son servicios que pertenecen al hilo principal de la app pero corren independientemete de la "interfaz grafica" o actividad, es decir que si inicias un servicio y pones una tarea en ese servicio la sigue ejecutando aun cuando "minimizes" la aplicacion (a menos que la actividad que lo llamo sea destruida...lo que detiene el servicio ) 
Pasate por aqui creo que te va a servir
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=es

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Podemos interactuar con la interfaz desde este hilo?

probablemente tendras el error [**NetworkOnMainThread**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) ya que estas realizando operaciones que modifican la UI, en el hilo principal.

Te recomiendo usar [**runOnUiThread()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {  

               //Realizar aquí tu proceso!                    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

otra opción es usar [**Asynctask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

o también [**Handler.post()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).